# Wagtail CMS style override

Tags: templates, overriding, customization, styling, wagtail

I'm building out a Wagtail admin at the moment and I have a Page model which, in the Admin, renders a few nested model forms via inline panels allowing for the addition of content by the user.  Due to Wagtail's rigid templates, some of my verbose_names for fields in the nested models get cut off in the UI.

As such i'm attempting to override the styling in the templates so that the verbose_names are not cutoff anymore. Here it is cutoff:

[image: cut off verbose name]

And here it is not cut off:
[image: not cut off]

So far I have gone the route of using wagtail hooks, specifically the `insert_global_admin_css` hook, but the browser returns a 404 and cannot find the file.  I cannot figure out where to place the file in the codebase for Wagtail to pick it up and override the default styling!

My hook implementation:

```html
@hooks.register('insert_global_admin_css', order=100)
def global_admin_css():
    return format_html(
        '<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{}">',
        static('css/admin.css')
    )
```

And the error coming back in the browser:

[image]

Help! TIA

Answer (score 1):

You aren't showing us your implementation of the `insert_global_admin_css` hook -- but that's the code that determines where your new CSS file should go!

An example from one of my wagtail sites:

```
@hooks.register("insert_global_admin_css", order=100)
def global_admin_css():
    """Add /static/admin_tweaks/wagtail.css."""
    return format_html('<link rel="stylesheet" href="{}">', static("admin_tweaks/wagtail.css"))
```

Comment: I've added the snippet as well as a screenshot of what i'm getting back from Chrome.  I suppose my issue is more filepath related than anything else.  I just don't have a solid enough understanding of how to define the path within my project to allow the browser to find it.

Comment: You defined the path when you specified static('css/admin.css') -- that means that within the same django app where this code lives, you need a file at static/css/admin.css. But the path that is getting written out in your html has an extra couple of directories in it, so I'm wondering if something is amiss either (1) with your STATIC_URL in settings, or, if this is the built-in dev server, (2) something missing in your urls.py for static file handling.